# Checking if Post author is equal to logged in user

Tags: session, if-statement, cakephp

A user can post a 'Tutorial', each tutorial is associated with its author via their 'user_id'.
My problem is I want to alter the view if the logged in user is viewing their own post (Tutorial).

CONTROLLER:

```
  public function view($id = null)
{
    $tutorial = $this->Tutorials->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users','Courses', 'TutorialComments.Users']
    ]);


    $tutorialComment = $this->Tutorials->TutorialComments->newEntity();

    $this->set(compact('tutorial', 'tutorialComment'));

}
```

VIEW:

```
<? if (($tutorial->user->id) === ($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id'))): ?> 

<p> hello </p>

 <? endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should access the logged in the controller through the Auth component and pass the user to the view

controller

```
$logged_user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');

$this->set(compact('tutorial', 'tutorialComment', 'logged_user_id '));
```

view

```
if($tutorial->user->id == $logged_user_id) {
    // your code here
}
```

Comment: When I tried this it is outputting in the view, 'user->id == $logged_user_id) { } ?>'

Comment: well you have to use php tags of course, this is basic php

Comment: <? if($tutorial->user->id == $logged_user_id) {
    
    
} ?>

Comment: With PHP tags still only outputting 'user->id == $logged_user_id) { } ?>'

Comment: Controller  :  public function view($id = null)
    {
        $tutorial = $this->Tutorials->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['Users','Courses', 'TutorialComments.Users']
        ]);

        $logged_user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        
        $tutorialComment = $this->Tutorials->TutorialComments->newEntity();
        
        $this->set(compact('tutorial', 'tutorialComment', 'logged_user_id'));
        
        
        
}

Comment: Short tags are deprecated

Comment: With [TinyAuth](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tinyauth/blob/master/docs/Authorization.md#authuserhelper) you also have direct access as `if ($tutorial->user->id === $this->AuthUser->id())` etc.